# vertical centering Side Navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

guys.
I'm pretty new to CSS and it's my first try to create a vertical navbar.
After learning that i need to use -40 margin for my `<li>` to center the text horizontal, i got the next challenge. 
I don't get it to center the text vertical.
Maybe someone could help me :-)

```css
body {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.nav {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: -8px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 0 -40;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}

.nav li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Webdesign</title>
</head>
  
<body>
  <ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">START</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things :

```
.nav li {
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 0 0 -40; // You forgot to define a unit, so it won't work. (40 what ? px, em, rem, %...)
}
```

I suggest you to reset margin and padding `* {margin:0; padding:0;}`, because you added a margin to your li to couterbalance the padding of th ul.

`.nav {height:100%;}` won't work if all parents (html, body, etc...) don't have a proper height defined.

You can achieve a vertical align in different way,
one would be :

```css
*{padding:0; margin:0;}
html, body {height:100%;}
body {
  font-family: Lato;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
div {
  display:table;
  height:100%;
}
.nav {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}

.nav li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">START</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

What I did is:

- Added a div wrapping the ul
- Added a height:100%; to html, body and that div
- Added display:table; to that div
- Added display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; to your .nav

Comment: Thanks for your help and even more thanks for that understandable explanation. XOXO

Comment: I'm glad if that helped. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.nav {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Webdesign</title>
</head>
  
<body>
  <ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">START</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, but thanks for the answer. I set the nav to a height of 100% to display the whole screen with the side navbar. And i want the text to be centered in that 100% "display" height.

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake! Just apply the following rule:

```
.nav {
    padding: 0;
}
```

and don't use any negative margins. Hope that helps you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox
you add to parent ul called in your code .nav

```
 display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
```

and to child elements (li)

```
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
align-self: center;
```

Flexbox can assure that you item will be 100% in middle verticaly using :

```
justify-content: center;
```